# Using jQuery to get multiple checkbox's value and output as comma separated String.

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have many checkboxs as below,

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="areaofinterest" value="home_coo" id="home_coo" class="Checkbox" > Cooking</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="areaofinterest" value="home_cra" id="home_cra" class="Checkbox"> Crafts</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="areaofinterest" value="home_dec" id="home_dec" class="Checkbox"> Decorating</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="areaofinterest" value="home_ent" id="home_ent" class="Checkbox"> Entertaining</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="areaofinterest" value="home_gar" id="home_gar" class="Checkbox"> Gardening</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="areaofinterest" value="home_hom" id="home_hom" class="Checkbox"> Home Improvement</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="areaofinterest" value="home_mar" id="home_mar" class="Checkbox"> Marriage</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="areaofinterest" value="home_par" id="home_par" class="Checkbox"> Parenting</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="areaofinterest" value="home_pet" id="home_pet" class="Checkbox" > Pets</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="areaofinterest" value="home_ret" id="home_ret" class="Checkbox"> Retirement</li>
```

How can I use jQuery to get the checked values and output as areaofinterest="home_coo,home_mar,home_pet" ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function:

```
$('.Checkbox:checked').map(function() {return this.value;}).get().join(',')
```

Breaking that down:

`$('.Checkbox:checked')` selects the checked checkboxes.

`.map(function() {return this.value;})` creates a jQuery object that holds an array containing the values of the checked checkboxes.

`.get()` returns the actual array.

`.join(',');` joins all of the elements of the array into a string, separated by a comma.

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nr2zU/)

Comment: Just an FYI - the "," within the join is not needed as it will add a comma by default when just using `join()`. Also good to note, this is the exact scenario that jQuery uses in the docs for `.map()`: http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nr2zU/683/): Make the comma separated string, store the string, then use the string to restore the checkboxes.

Comment: can I display it in List??

Answer (score 4):

```
var areaofinterest = '';

$('[name="areaofinterest"]')​.each(function(i,e) {
    var comma = areaofinterest.length===0?'':',';
    areaofinterest += (comma+e.value);
})​;
```

To get only checked boxes value :

```
var areaofinterest = '';

$('[name="areaofinterest"]')​.each(function(i,e) {
    if ($(e).is(':checked')) {
        var comma = areaofinterest.length===0?'':',';
        areaofinterest += (comma+e.value);
    }
})​;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/97vrS/1/)

You could also do:

```
var areaofinterest = [];
$('[name="areaofinterest"]:checked').each(function(i,e) {
    areaofinterest.push(e.value);
});

areaofinterest = areaofinterest.join(',');
```

And there's probably a bunch of other ways to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = "";
$("checkbox[name=areaofinterest]").each(function() { 
    values += $(this).val() + ",";
});

values = values.substring(0, values.length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var areaofinterest= "";

$("input[type=\"checkbox\"]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        if (areaofinterest !== "") areaofinterest += ",";

        areaofinterest += $(this).value();
    }
});
```

Comment: He wants to sum values not id's

Comment: His exact specification was: "How can I use jQuery to get the checked values and output as areaofinterest="home_coo,home_mar,home_pet"?"

Comment: In this context his IDs had the same value as his "values", but I see your point.  Amended my sample.

Answer (score 0):

Or you use can do using array like shown below

```
 var checkBoxArray = new Array();
 var areaofinterest = '';

 $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
        checkBoxArray .push($(this).attr("value"));

});

  if (checkBoxArray .length == 0) {
     } else {
     while (checkBoxArray .length != 0) {
            if (checkBoxArray .length == 1) {
                areaofinterest += checkBoxArray .pop();
            } else {
                areaofinterest += (checkBoxArray .pop() + ",");
                 }
            }
}
console.log(areaofinterest);
```

though you will get String in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var mode = [];
            jQuery("input[name='mode[]']:checked").each(function(i) {
                mode.push($(this).val());
            });
```