# Capture the value of two set of checkboxes into two separate strings

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have two set of checkboxes, and the value of the checked checkboxes should be mapped into two different strings. I understood on how to use the map function as mentioned here [Using jQuery to get multiple checkbox's value and output as comma separated String.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723297/using-jquery-to-get-multiple-checkboxs-value-and-output-as-comma-separated-stri)

But just cant understand how to separate these two sets.

VV

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_36_0" name="q36_VV[]" value="CC" />
<label for="input_36_0">CC</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_36_1" name="AA[]" value="BB" />
<label for="input_36_1">B</label>
<br>
<label class="form-label-left" id="label_37" for="input_37">XX</label>

    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_37_0" name="q37_businessType[]" value="YY" />
    <label for="input_37_0">YY</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" id="input_37_0" name="q37_businessType[]" value="ZZ" />
    <label for="input_37_0">ZZ</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the id attribute

```
var x1 = $('.form-checkbox[id^="input_36_"]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get().join();

var x2 = $('.form-checkbox[id^="input_37_"]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get().join();
```