# Using jQuery's .val() on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery's `.val()` to get the data from my amCharts period selector to a div on my page. It works, but only brings in one value. The .amChartsInputField has two input areas that contain text.

I have noticed on the jQuery documentation that `.val()` does only work with one element. Is there a way a way to tweak this to bring in multiple objects?

My script below:

jQuery:

```
chart1.addListener("rendered", function(e) {
  e.chart.periodSelector.addListener("changed", function() {
    var date = $(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField").val();
    $("#date-div p").text( date );
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="date-div"><p>information pulled</p></div>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have two input fields with same class, then you have to loop through the class using each() method and concat the result

Comment: You'll need to iterate over the matched elements somehow, getting their individual values in turn. If you wanted to return comma separated values, there's a question (and an answer by myself) on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11723297/552438

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could collect all of the values into an array using jQuery's [**`map()`**](https://api.jquery.com/map/) function:

```js
// for each match, "map" the value into an array
var dates = $(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();

// join the values together and assign to the date-div
$("#date-div p").text(dates.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- made up HTML that fits your selectors -->
<div class="amChartsPeriodSelector">
  <input type="text" class="amChartsInputField" value="2014-10-10" />
  <input type="text" class="amChartsInputField" value="2015-11-10" />
</div>

<div id="date-div"><p></p></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Cory, much appreciated and I have learnt a new jquery function map();

Answer (score 5):

You can make it an array using `map` and `get`

```
var date = $(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField").map(function(){
   return this.value; // simple but you could also use $(this).val();
}).get(); // now date is an array
```

If you want to concat you can do it like `$("#date-div p").text( date.join(" ") );` or use an index.

Comment: Thank you Amit, your answer and Cory's help me alot.

Comment: @jasonh glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The `date` variable gets updated only once (with the first element's val()), which means you don't get an array by doing that. If you want to do something for each separate value then you can do

```
var elements = $('.elements');
var value;
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    value = $(elements[i]).val();
    //now do something.. for example:
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: That first sentence is the complete opposite of what actually happens, as already mentioned *in the question*. jQuery getters (unless explicitly stated otherwise) only ever look at the *first* matched element.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do something like that:

```
var date = [];
$(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField").each(function() {
    date.push($(this).val());
});
```